# Databricks Delta Lake + ADSL + Presto

Tags: azure, databricks, presto, delta-lake

Databricks has just released [a public preview of Delta Lake and Presto integration](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/presto-compatibility.html). I'm new to Azure, and the link has multiple mentions of EMR and Athena but lack Azure keywords. So I have to ask a stupid question:

*Am I right that Presto integration is only for AWS since Azure doesn't have Presto PaaS?*

P.S. Have Databricks any plans for Delta Lake and Synapse/Polybase integration in nearest future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Delta Lake Presto integration](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/presto-compatibility.html) is based on "symlinks" and they are supported in Presto since long. On Azure, you can conveniently provision Presto using

- [Starburst Presto Kubernetes + Azure AKS](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/azure.html) (recommended)
- Starburst Presto for HDInsights, freely [available in HDInsights Marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en/marketplace/apps/starburst.starburst-presto) (more of a "legacy" option)
- there is also some Azure offering from Qubole and perhaps others

Bear in mind, however, that "symlinks"-based integration has certain limits. Here, at Starburst, we're working on native Delta Lake support, without need to create "symlinks".

Comment: thank you for the answer! Why did you say that HDInsight Presto is a "legacy" option? The first option link "Presto on Microsoft Azure" is focused on HDInsight

Comment: I think we don't provide the latest Presto version for HDInsights, but I may be wrong. Anyway, Kubernetes based solution is likely to provide more elasticity.